# Parsing XML in Powershell and get all xsd-validation errors

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, powershell-5.1

my goal is to validate a `xml` against a `xsd schema` file in `powershell 5.1`. So far, I 've got the following code. Actually it works and show me the error. But the issue is, only the very first validation error get write to consol. If I fix the error inside the xml, run the script again, it shows me the next error.

I did lots of researach, but I can't find a way to get it run and log all existing validation errors.

Do you know what's wrong?

````
$xmlPath = "C:\path\to\my\product.xml"
$xsdPath = "C:\path\to\my\product.xsd"
$targetNamespace = "myNAMESPACE"

function Test-XmlBySchema
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([bool])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ })]
        [ValidatePattern('\.xml')]
        [string]$XmlFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ })]
        [ValidatePattern('\.xsd')]
        [string]$SchemaPath
    )

    BEGIN {
    $failCount = 0
    $failureMessages = ""
    $fileName = ""
    }

    PROCESS {
        
        foreach($eR in $error ){
            try {
                [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $XmlFile -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
                $xml.Schemas.Add($targetNamespace, $SchemaPath) | Out-Null
                $xml.Validate($null)
                Write-Verbose "Successfully validated $XmlFile against schema ($SchemaPath)"
            }
        
            catch {
                $err = $_.Exception.Message
                Write-Verbose "Failed to validate '$XmlFile' against schema '$SchemaPath' "
                Write-Verbose  $err
                
                #Write-Host "Script Error: $_.ScriptStackTrace"
                #$result = $false
            }

            finally {
                #result
                #failCount
                #handler to ensure we always close the reader sicne it locks files
                #$reader.Close()
               # $Error[0].exception.GetType().fullname
               $error.count
            }
        } # End of Loop
    }
}

Test-XmlBySchema -XmlFile $xmlPath -SchemaPath $xsdPath -Verbose –ErrorAction SilentlyContinue```
````

Comment: Is script closing because you are getting into the finally block?  In the catch add a continue to skip the finally.

Comment: @jdweng Adding ```Continue``` inside the `CATCH` block still leads to only catching the very first xsd-validation error. Any other ideas to figure out the issue?

Comment: You can use c# code inside a ps script.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-schema-xsd-validation-with-xmlschemaset?force_isolation=true

Comment: Any other option to do it just with powershell standard tools / code?

Comment: c# is standard PS.  PS is written in c#.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am not a ddeveloper. The example is still a bit tricky.

Comment: It looks like, that powershell occur an error, importing the .cs file with the following code inside that import file: `using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;` Do you know, how to get it run?

Answer (score 0):

I started the translation.  This is what I got so far

```
$URL = 'http://www.contoso.com/books'
$xsdFilename = 'books.xsd'
$xxmFilename = 'books.xml'

Function booksSettingsValidationEventHandler
{
   param ([object] $sender, [System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs] $e)

   if($e.Severity -eq [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSeverityType]::Warning)
   {
       Console.Write("WARNING: ");
       Console.WriteLine($e.Message);
   }
   else
   {
      if ($e.Severity -eq [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSeverityType]::Error)
      {
         Write-Host 'ERROR'
         Write-Host $e.Message
      }
   }
}


$booksSettings = [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings]::new();

$booksSettings.Schemas.Add($URL, $xsdFilename);
$booksSettings.ValidationType = [System.Xml.ValidationType]::Schema;


$booksSettings.ValidationEventHandler += booksSettingsValidationEventHandler;

$books = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create([string]$xmlFilename, [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings]$booksSettings);

while ($books.Read()) {  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Could I kindly ask you again? I received the following error messages: 

The Validation property was not found for this object. Make sure that the property exists and can be set. 


 `$booksSettings.Validation += booksSettingsValidationEventHandler;`
 
Several ambiguous overloads were found for "Create" and argument count: "2".

`$books = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($xmlFilename, $booksSettings)` 
 
It is not possible to call a method for an expression that has the NULL.

`while ($books.Read()) { }`

Comment: Change From : $booksSettings.Validation To : $booksSettings.ValidationEventHandler Try : $books = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create([string]$xmlFilename, [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings]$booksSettings)  The other error is due to $books being null due to the first error.